# Drawing digits with tkinter and entring them in a neural network trained for digit recognition

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, mnist

This is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from numpy import argmax,array
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image


width=28
height =28

(Xtrain,Ytrain) ,(Xtest,Ytest)=mnist.load_data()

new_model=tf.keras.models.load_model('digitrecognizing_model.model')

def pxl_binary_val(image,index):
    if image.getpixel(index)==(255,255,255):
        return 0
    else:
        return 255


def paint(event):
    x1,y1=(event.x-1),(event.y-1)
    x2,y2=(event.x+1),(event.y+1)
    c.create_oval(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='black',outline='black')

def save_as_png(event):
    c.postscript(file = r'C:\Users\amelbarouni\Desktop\python yassinne\ppyytthhoonn\sample' + '.eps')
    root.destroy()
    img = Image.open(r'C:\Users\amelbarouni\Desktop\python yassinne\ppyytthhoonn\sample' + '.eps')
    img.save(r'C:\Users\amelbarouni\Desktop\python yassinne\ppyytthhoonn\sample' + '.png', 'png')
    img=Image.open(r'C:\Users\amelbarouni\Desktop\python yassinne\ppyytthhoonn\sample.png')
    img_pxl_vals=np.zeros((28,28))


    width ,height=img.size

    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            img_pxl_vals[j,i]=pxl_binary_val(img,(j,i))
            
    imgtest=img_pxl_vals.T
    plt.imshow(imgtest,cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()
    imgtest=np.array(imgtest)
    prediction=new_model.predict([imgtest])
    print(prediction)

root=Tk()
root.title('sample')
c=Canvas(root,width=width,height=height,bg='white')
c.pack(expand=YES)
c.bind('<B1-Motion>',paint)
root.bind('<Return>',save_as_png)


root.mainloop()
```

but I'm facing this error , I think it has to do with the shape of the pixels matrix I'm trying to  input in the neural network,I've tried to flatten the matrix but that hasn't worked and the transposing of the matrix that I did was because when I was showing the image on the plot I noticed it was rotated90 degrees to the left.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\Desktop\python yassinne\ppyytthhoonn\mlkjj.py", line 55, in save_as_png
    prediction=new_model.predict([imgtest])
  File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 1147, in autograph_handler
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\amelbarouni\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 248, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (None, 1)
    
    Call arguments received:
      • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)',)
      • training=False
      • mask=None
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

EDIT:

this is my code for creating the model
Does it have any issues concerning the input's shape that could be causing the error?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.layers import  Dense
from tensorflow import keras
from numpy import argmax
(Xtrain,Ytrain) ,(Xtest,Ytest)=mnist.load_data()
model=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain,epochs=3)
```

Comment: error shows problem in line `prediction=new_model.predict([imgtest])` - so first you should check what you have in variables in this line. It seems that `imgtest` is empty because error shows `"... but received input with shape (None, 1)"`. OR maybe it expects single `imgtest` instead of list `[imgtest]` - or rather array 1D with size `784` instead of image 2D with size`28x28` -  `"... expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, ..."`

Comment: yeah i tried imgtest.flatten() but it doesn't seem to work . other ideas of how to fix it would be more than welcome.

Comment: did you try to use `predict(imgtest.flatten())`  without `[ ]`?

Comment: Input 0 of layer "dense" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784, but received input with shape (None, 1)

Comment: this is what i got .thing is i'm not getting why this error keeps showing up and I'm absolutely not entring a matrix of shape (None, 1).

Comment: maybe use `print()` to debug it. use `print()` to see what you have in variables - `print(imgtest)`, `print(imgtest.shape)` and maybe check also what you have before `np.array(imgtest)`. Maybe you shouldn't use `np.array(imgtest)`

Answer (score 0):

I build own model to test code and all problem is that it needs shape `(1,784)` but you use `(28,28)` and `flatten()` creates shape `(784,)`

```
imgtest = img_pxl_vals.reshape(1, 28*28)#.astype('float32')

prediction = model.predict(imgtest)

print('prediction:', prediction)
print('argmax:', np.argmax(prediction, axis=-1))
```

---

**EDIT:**

You don't have to create postcript, convert to png, and read png. You can put values directly in array

```
def paint(event):
    x1 = event.x - 1
    y1 = event.y - 1
    x2 = event.x + 1
    y2 = event.y + 1

    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black', outline='black')

    # put directly in array
    if 0 <= x1 and 0 <= y1 and x2 <= 28 and y2 <= 28:
        img_pxl_vals[y1:y2, x1:x2] = 255
```

Eventually you can keep it in PNG using directly `pillow` Image

```
    img = ~img_pxl_vals #.astype('uint8')  # use `~` to invert colors: black to white, white to black
    img = Image.fromarray(img, 'L')
    img.save('sample.png', 'png')
```

---

Full working code with other changes:

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import datetime

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES` for constants

WIDHT  = 28  # PEP8: spaces around `=`
HEIGHT = 28  # PEP8: spaces around `=`

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions after imports and constans

def paint(event):
    x1 = event.x - 1
    y1 = event.y - 1
    x2 = event.x + 1
    y2 = event.y + 1

    canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black', outline='black')

    # put directly in array
    if 0 <= x1 and 0 <= y1 and x2 <= 28 and y2 <= 28:
        pixels[y1:y2, x1:x2] = 255

def save_as_png(event):

    root.destroy()

    print('pixels.shape:', pixels.shape)
    #print(pixels)

    plt.imshow(pixels, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
    plt.show()

    print('flatten:', pixels.flatten().shape)

    imgtest = pixels.reshape(1, 28*28).astype('float32')
    print('imgtest.shape:', imgtest.shape)
    imgtest /= 255

    prediction = model.predict(imgtest)
    print('prediction:', prediction)
    print('argmax:', np.argmax(prediction, axis=-1))

    img = ~pixels  # use `~` to invert colors: black to white, white to black
    #print(img)
    img = Image.fromarray(img, 'L')
    filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('sample-%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%s.png')
    img.save(filename, 'png')

# --- main ---

pixels = np.zeros((28,28), dtype='uint8')  # global arrray

model = keras.models.load_model('digitrecognizing_model.model')

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('sample')

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDHT, height=HEIGHT, bg='white')
canvas.pack(expand=True)

canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', paint)
root.bind('<Return>', save_as_png)

root.mainloop()
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

---

**EDIT:**

Code to generate model - so everyone can simply copy and test all code.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('keras:', keras.__version__)


print('loading ...')
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print('shape x_train:', X_train.shape)
print('shape x_test :', X_test.shape)

# -----

image_index = 35

print('digit:', y_train[image_index])
#print('data:',   x_train[image_index])

#plt.imshow(x_train[image_index], cmap='Greys')
#plt.show()

# --- create model ---

num_pixels = X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]

x_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], num_pixels).astype('float32')
x_test  = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],   num_pixels).astype('float32')

# convert 0.255 to 0-1
x_train /= 255
x_test  /= 255

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test  = to_categorical(y_test)
print('categorical:', y_train.shape)

num_classes = y_train.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(num_pixels, input_dim=num_pixels, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# --- fit ---

batch_size = 128
epochs = 10

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])

model.save("digitrecognizing_model.model")
```

Comment: i'm still getting this error : ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 28, 28), found shape=(None, 784)

Comment: does it have to do with the way I'm creating the model ?

Comment: and just a question why do you use axis=-1 as a parameter in the NumPy argmax function?

Comment: it seems you create model in different way and it needs diffferent shape as input. You may need `reshape(1, 28, 28)` instead of `reshape(1, 28*28)` (which means `reshape(1, 784)`. I started with code which could work with many images in `predict([image1, image2])` so it could gives many predictions and I needed `axis=-1` to get many results. Without `axis=-1` it was giving one result for many images. But when it works with single image then you can skip `axis=-1`

Comment: Yeah i worked after i used reshape(1, 28, 28) as you said and I seen that I made a mistake in the creation of the model and used 128 output neurons. But I think the model is overfitting do you have any ideas to avoid that?